# Basic authentication auto login but no credentials shows in URL

Tags: http, authentication, https, basic-authentication, solrj

I am trying to achieve auto login with given credentials in the back while users can directly see a logged in web page so that they don't need to type or know the credentials. Is there a way to do this without any credentials show up in the URL from user's side?

Answer (score 0):

If you only have a link to work with, this is not possible.

Comment: No, not just a link. Got Solr's web sever.

Comment: Are you controlling both the authenticated server, and where they are coming from? Where are they coming from?

Comment: I do have access to them. One is Solr running on a Linux box the other is a LDAP server .